# How to skip array [ for child node for "vpoShipId" : [ in xml to json conversion

Tags: arrays, xslt, multidimensional-array, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0

Request to share template to skip the array [ for child node only  "vpoShipId" :[ in xml to json conversion.

The only issue with the child node as array tag [ in "vpoShipId" :[
Trying with the below xslt code but not able to skip the array tag [ for child node.

xml path - PO_Message/vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList/vpoShipId

Input xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:PO_Message
    xmlns:ns0="http://test.com/Test">
    <domainId>MAIL</domainId>
    <hubDomainId>MAIL</hubDomainId>
    <isForReference>false</isForReference>
    <status>releasedToVendor</status>
    <docStatus>active</docStatus>
    <editingStatus>confirmed</editingStatus>
    <vpoNo>28218</vpoNo>
    <vpoDate>2021-02-23</vpoDate>
    <instructions>METAL-No Size:1360600001-Article Number</instructions>
    <businessRefNo>2818</businessRefNo>
    <totalItems>1</totalItems>
    <totalQty>160</totalQty>
    <season>
        <code>F21</code>
    </season>
    <custId>
        <refNo>C000001</refNo>
    </custId>
    <vendorId>
        <vendorCode>41843</vendorCode>
    </vendorId>
    <headerFactory>
        <refNo>F000026</refNo>
        <factCode>900088</factCode>
    </headerFactory>
    <vpoItemList>
        <itemNo>19979-2021-0002-41843</itemNo>
        <itemName>Base Camp 6 Footprint</itemName>
        <customerItemNo>19979</customerItemNo>
        <lotNo>1</lotNo>
        <itemDesc>Base Camp 6 Footprint</itemDesc>
        <shipQty>160</shipQty>
        <planedQty>160</planedQty>
        <qtyPerExportCarton>160</qtyPerExportCarton>
        <qtyPerInnerCarton>160</qtyPerInnerCarton>
        <factCode>900088</factCode>
        <refNo>19979-2021-0002-41843-1</refNo>
        <uom>
            <code>PCS</code>
        </uom>
        <brand>
            <code>MAIL</code>
        </brand>
        <itemId>
            <itemNo>19979-2021-0002-41843</itemNo>
        </itemId>
        <portOfLanding>
            <code>DLC Dalian</code>
        </portOfLanding>
        <vpoItemCsList>
            <itemLotNo>19979-2021-0002-41843-Lot1</itemLotNo>
            <vpoItemColorRef>METAL</vpoItemColorRef>
            <vpoItemColorId>
                <refNo>GUNMETAL</refNo>
                <shortName>METAL</shortName>
            </vpoItemColorId>
            <vpoItemSizeId>
                <refNo>No Size</refNo>
                <displayName>No Size</displayName>
            </vpoItemSizeId>
            <itemId>
                <iteamNo>19979-2021-0002-41843</iteamNo>
            </itemId>
            <lotNo>1</lotNo>
        </vpoItemCsList>
        <factId>
            <factCode>900088</factCode>
        </factId>
    </vpoItemList>
    <vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList>
        <qty>160</qty>
        <refNo>00001/19979-2021-0002-41843-1</refNo>
        <vpoItemRef
            xmlns:ns1="http://sap.com/xi/SAPGlobal/GDT">19979-2021-0002-41843-1
        </vpoItemRef>
        <vpoItemId>
            <itemId>
                <itemNo>19979-2021-0002-41843</itemNo>
            </itemId>
        </vpoItemId>
        <vpoShipRef>00001</vpoShipRef>
        <vpoShipId>
            <shipmentNo>00001</shipmentNo>
            <originalShipmentDate>2021-08-17</originalShipmentDate>
            <shipmentDate>2021-08-23</shipmentDate>
            <originalInDcDate>2021-09-15</originalInDcDate>
            <inDcDate>2021-09-15</inDcDate>
            <refNo>00001/19979-2021-0002-41843-1</refNo>
            <shipMode>
                <code>3</code>
            </shipMode>
            <finalDestination>
                <code>0001</code>
            </finalDestination>
            <portOfLoading>
                <code>DLC Dalian</code>
            </portOfLoading>
        </vpoShipId>
        <shipMode>
            <code>3</code>
        </shipMode>
        <portOfLoading>
            <code>DLC Dalian</code>
        </portOfLoading>
    </vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList>
    <vpoShipDtlCsGroupList>
        <itemLotNo>19979-2021-0002-41843-Lot1</itemLotNo>
        <shipmentNo>00001</shipmentNo>
        <colorSizeQty>160</colorSizeQty>
        <refNo>00001/19979-2021-0002-41843-1/GUNMETAL/No Size</refNo>
        <vpoItemRef>19979-2021-0002-41843-1</vpoItemRef>
        <vpoItemId>
            <itemId>
                <itemNo>19979-2021-0002-41843</itemNo>
            </itemId>
        </vpoItemId>
        <vpoShipRef>00001/19979-2021-0002-41843-1</vpoShipRef>
        <vpoItemColorRef>METAL</vpoItemColorRef>
        <vpoItemSizeRef>No Size</vpoItemSizeRef>
        <vpoShipDtlColorRef>1</vpoShipDtlColorRef>
        <vpoShipDtlSizeRef>1</vpoShipDtlSizeRef>
    </vpoShipDtlCsGroupList>
</ns0:PO_Message>
```

Expected Json Output File

```
{ "domainId" : "MAIL",
    "hubDomainId" : "MAIL",
    "isForReference" : "false",
    "status" : "releasedToVendor",
    "docStatus" : "active",
    "editingStatus" : "confirmed",
    "vpoNo" : "12118",
    "vpoDate" : "2021-02-23",
    "instructions" : "METAL-No Size:1360600001-Article Number",
    "businessRefNo" : "2818",
    "totalItems" : "1",
    "totalQty" : "160",
    "season" : 
    { "code" : "F21" },
    "custId" : 
    { "refNo" : "C000001" },
    "vendorId" : 
    { "vendorCode" : "41843" },
    "headerFactory" : 
    { "refNo" : "F000026",
      "factCode" : "900088" },
    "vpoItemList" : 
    [ 
      { "itemNo" : "19979-2021-0002-41843",
        "itemName" : "Base Camp 6 Footprint",
        "customerItemNo" : "19979",
        "lotNo" : "1",
        "itemDesc" : "Base Camp 6 Footprint",
        "shipQty" : "160",
        "planedQty" : "160",
        "qtyPerExportCarton" : "160",
        "qtyPerInnerCarton" : "160",
        "factCode" : "900088",
        "refNo" : "19979-2021-0002-41843-1",
        "uom" : 
        { "code" : "PCS" },
        "brand" : 
        { "code" : "WIND" },
        "itemId" : 
        { "itemNo" : "19979-2021-0002-41843" },
        "portOfLanding" : 
        { "code" : "DLC Dalian" },
        "vpoItemCsList" : 
        [ 
          { "itemLotNo" : "19979-2021-0002-41843-Lot1",
            "vpoItemColorRef" : "METAL",
            "vpoItemColorId" : 
            { "refNo" : "GUNMETAL",
              "shortName" : "METAL" },
            "vpoItemSizeId" : 
            { "refNo" : "No Size",
              "displayName" : "No Size" },
            "itemId" : 
            { "iteamNo" : "19979-2021-0002-41843" },
            "lotNo" : "1" } ],
        "factId" : 
        { "factCode" : "900088" } } ],
    "vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList" : 
    [ 
      [ 
        { "qty" : "160",
          "refNo" : "00001\/19979-2021-0002-41843-1",
          "vpoItemRef" : "19979-2021-0002-41843-1",
          "vpoItemId" : 
          { "itemId" : 
            { "itemNo" : "19979-2021-0002-41843" } },
          "vpoShipRef" : "00001",
          "vpoShipId" : 
          
            { "shipmentNo" : "00001",
              "originalShipmentDate" : "2021-08-17",
              "shipmentDate" : "2021-08-23",
              "originalInDcDate" : "2021-09-15",
              "inDcDate" : "2021-09-15",
              "refNo" : "00001\/19979-2021-0002-41843-1",
              "shipMode" : 
              { "code" : "3" },
              "finalDestination" : 
              { "code" : "0001" },
              "portOfLoading" : 
              { "code" : "DLC Dalian" } } ,
          "shipMode" : 
          { "code" : "3" },
          "portOfLoading" : 
          { "code" : "DLC Dalian" } } ] ],
    "vpoShipDtlCsGroupList" : 
    [ 
      [ 
        { "itemLotNo" : "19979-2021-0002-41843-Lot1",
          "shipmentNo" : "00001",
          "colorSizeQty" : "160",
          "refNo" : "00001\/19979-2021-0002-41843-1\/GUNMETAL\/No Size",
          "vpoItemRef" : "19979-2021-0002-41843-1",
          "vpoItemId" : 
          { "itemId" : 
            { "itemNo" : "19979-2021-0002-41843" } },
          "vpoShipRef" : "00001\/19979-2021-0002-41843-1",
          "vpoItemColorRef" : "METAL",
          "vpoItemSizeRef" : "No Size",
          "vpoShipDtlColorRef" : "1",
          "vpoShipDtlSizeRef" : "1" } ] ] }
```

XLST Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*" priority="5">
    <xsl:variable name="json-xml">
      <map>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </map>        
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($json-xml, map { 'indent' : true() })"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
    <string key="{local-name()}">{.}</string>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[(*) and . castable as xs:double]">
    <number key="{local-name()}">{.}</number>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[* and not(*[6])]">
    <map key="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </map>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[* and *[6]]">
    <array key="{local-name()}">
        <map>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </map>
    </array>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList | vpoShipDtlCsGroupList" priority="10">
    <array key="{local-name()}">
        <array>
          <map>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </map>          
        </array>
    </array>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

Add a template

```
  <xsl:template match="vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList/vpoShipId">
      <map key="{local-name()}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </map>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, when we have more than 1 line item then the xslt code thrown an error message as ''The result is: Error: xml-to-json: duplicate key value {vpoItemList}". The vpoItemList, vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList & vpoShipDtlCsGroupList are the occurances 0 to Unbounded.  In general the message can contain more than 1 line item. Not able to find the exact code to increse the lineitems occurances are 0-Unbounded. Please help the place where i need to make the code change to accept 0-unbounded line items.

Comment: @raviteja, consider to ask a new question where you reduce the sample data and your tested code to that particular problem. It is not clear how your input looks and which JSON (array?) you want if you have several items of the same name.

Comment: The given json file is having only 1 line item...Nodes "vpoItemList": [ , "vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList": [ [ &     "vpoShipDtlCsGroupList": [ [ is having multipel line items. I can attach the multiple line items xml file .

Comment: The attached sample xml file and sample json file is having only 1 line item...Nodes "vpoItemList": [ , "vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList": [ [ and "vpoShipDtlCsGroupList": [ [ . In real time we have multiple line items. several items of the same name. I can attach the multiple line items xml file .. <vpoItemList>...</vpoItemList><vpoItemList>...</vpoItemList><vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList>.....</vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList><vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList>.....</vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList><vpoShipDtlCsGroupList>....</vpoShipDtlCsGroupList><vpoShipDtlCsGroupList>....<vpoShipDtlCsGroupList>